# Are gack's on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Was reading through the homepage, looking for anything needing edits or flags, when I read [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184333/salesforce-error-id-1366385420-22703-1478489697-internal-server-error-500). Once I was done with an edit, I noticed [Adrian Larson♦'s answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/184336/10382), and a line in it caught my eye:

> Another way is to post your experience on Stack Exchange. You can post the gack ID and stack trace ID, along with information on how it was that you encountered our lovely message. We will be able to find it there when doing our investigation.

While writing this question, I found a [relevant meta discussion](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1937/tagging-questions-that-contain-gack-identifiers) which led to the creation of the [gack tag](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gack), but the question didnt address the subject I'd like to bring up:

Is there anything we, the community on Stack Exchange, can do about questions which include a gack, which are not caused by an error in the askers code? Are there Salesforce dev's who monitor this tag to any degree?

As someone who considers themselves an average user of the site, if the best I can provide is a summary of what a gack is, and an answer which can be summarized to "You need to contact support", is it useful to direct people here? Especially if a mod replies with the same information?

Comment: There are definitely SF development team members that are active here like Doug Chasman so it is worth posting the gack's here, but ultimately they can only normally be resolved by support. It is possible that other site users will know a workaround though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I for one work for Salesforce and can look up at least basic details behind GACKs. I know there are other members of R&D who at least lurk the site, and as Dave Humm mentioned some are quite active.

There's no guarantee anybody with access to do look up GACKs will see your question, but the odds aren't terrible, and I do see references to stackexchange posts in more bugs than you'd expect. As long as it isn't degrading the site for others (add the gack tag to ignored tags if so?) it seems at reasonably beneficial to all as far as I'm concerened.